# Getting a LinearLayout by ID in recyclerview causes NullPointerException error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am adding 3 LinearLayouts inside of a RecyclerView. I then add content to these 3 views in which I am setting their ID to be unique (panel1, panel2, panel3).

All 3 layouts are visible in the recyclerview, using layout inspector I can see all 3 layouts with corresponding ID.

When I add a view using addView to panel1, everything is fine and my panel page gets added, when trying to add to panel2 or panel3 - I get the null object error.

Is this because the view is hidden to the right hand side of the phone screen so its unable to get its ID?

Here is my adding view code

```
LinearLayout main1 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel1);
LinearLayout main2 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel2);
LinearLayout main3 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel3);


main1.addView(keyPanel1);
main2.addView(keyPanel2);
main3.addView(keyPanel3);
```

main2.addView(), main3.addView() return errors.

Here is My ID xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <item type="id" name="panel1" />
    <item type="id" name="panel2" />
    <item type="id" name="panel3" />
</resources>
```

In my recycler view adapter I am just setting the IDs each time I run through

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout recyclerLayout;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_layout);
            layoutNum++;

            if(layoutNum == 1){
                recyclerLayout.setId(R.id.panel1);
            }
            if(layoutNum == 2){
                recyclerLayout.setId(R.id.panel2);
            }
            if(layoutNum == 3){
                recyclerLayout.setId(R.id.panel3);
            }
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_text);
        }
    }
```

When debugging, main1 is set to a linearlayout while main2,main3 are NULL

```
LinearLayout main1 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel1); // Assigned
LinearLayout main2 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel2); // NULL
LinearLayout main3 = browserPanelApplet.findViewById(R.id.panel3); //NULL
```

I went into this thinking I can access all generated IDs inside recyclerview but have hit this block.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I did a recycler in Java (and I think I never needed set IDs manually), but... check if layoutNum is being updated correctly. You can also try opening layout inspector and check if the layouts have different IDs

Answer (score 0):

The way you are approaching this seems quite convoluted, I would recommend having a read of the `RecyclerView` documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to give you more of an understanding about how the `RecyclerView` works and what role the adapter and especially the `onBindViewHolder` method plays.

However to answer your specific question, you are right in the sense that the views are `null` because they are offscreen. One of the main reasons for using a `RecyclerView`, which you can read about in the documentation, is to reuse (recycle) the views to display different content when scrolling, so it doesn't have to waste resources initialising the entire list at once.